# How to store the auto generated Firestore document ID in my custom ID using Angular

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

[image]

I want to store the auro generated ID in campaignID,

This is my function that stores campaigns :

```
  saveCampaign(campaignFields: Campaign) {
    return from(
      addDoc(collection(this.firestoreDB, 'mail_campaign'), campaignFields)
    );
  }
```

what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing similar thing using AngularFirestore injectable, You can give it a try like below

```
import { AngularFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";

 constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
  }   
 async  saveCampaign(campaignFields: Campaign) {
   let id = this.afs.createId();
   campaignFields.compainId = id;
    await this.afs.collection('mail_campaign').doc(id).set(campaignFields);
  }
```

Comment: Works great ! thank you, you saved a lot of my time

Comment: What is the solution for v9?